# It is possible to do apply statistical inference to a derived metric?

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling

I have two log-normally distributed variables.

$\ln(X)$ ~ $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

$\ln(Y)$ ~ $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$

Through statistical inference I can get a confidence interval for the median or mean of either variable. However, I was wondering if it is possible to get a confidence interval for the ratio of sums of the variables.

The application:

Let's say I have a sample of the distribution of clicks and impressions on 
different websites. Both clicks and impressions are log-normally distributed.

```
Web         Clicks    Impressions
web1        1500      4000
web2        1000      5000
web3        3000      4500
...
web4        900       3200
```

A common derived metric is click-through rate which is

```
CTR = sum(clicks)/sum(impressions)
```

Is it possible to calculate the confidence interval of CTR?

Comment: 1. You only define two variables in your question ($X$ and $Y$); you can either form a ratio or a sum with two variables, but then you only have one and both ratio and sum are binary operators. You need more than two variables to do that.  2. Clicks and impressions are both *counts*. Neither can actually be lognormally distributed.

Comment: You could also compute for each site it's CTR value: $c_j = clicks_j / impressions_j$ and work on that variable to get a confidence interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapping is totally possible here. The idea behind bootstrapping is to simulate a distribution of samples (i.e. lists of websites) that you *could have* measured from. The shape of this distribution should give you a sense of the *sampling error* around a metric you compute on your real sample. To generate a bootstrap distribution simply do the following:

1) Randomly sample, with replacement, a new list of websites from your current list that's the same size as your current list. For example, if you had 10 websites, generate a new list of 10 websites which will be in a randomly shuffled order and contain random repeats of your original list.
2) Compute your CTR metric for this new *bootstrapped* sample
3) Store it in a list/array, and repeat step 1)
4) Repeat steps 1-3 5000-10000 times

By the end of this process you will have a list of CTRs 5000-10000 long depending on what you chose in 4). This list, is your *bootstrap* distribution of CTRs. It simulates the *sampling error* surrounding your original CTR metric. From the sampling error, there are many ways to get confidence intervals. A simple way to get 95% confidence intervals is to take the values at the 2.5% and 97.5% percentiles of this distribution. However, given you're dealing with log-normal data, the percentile method may not ideal to account for the shape of the bootstrap distribution. There are a host of methods, functions, and packages in R and Python that can compute these more advanced bootstrap metrics (e.g. bias-corrected-accelerated). [Here's a nice blog post (not authored by me)](https://garstats.wordpress.com/2018/01/23/bias-correction/) that describes why you might consider a more advanced bootstrap metric. In general the basic 4 steps are always part of the process.